# How to use _fields option in odoo 8

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8, openerp-8

I am new to odoo.

Is anyone have tutorial of using _fields feature in odoo 8 ?

In odoo 8, _columns is deprecated.

> A common pattern in OpenERP was to do Model fields introspection using _columns property. From 8.0 _columns is deprecated by _fields that contains list of consolidated fields instantiated using old or new API.

There is no clear documentation about _fields options.

Please give a right tutorial on this.

Comment: In the official page (https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/ -section *Reference*-) you can find the basic documentation to start programming in Odoo. If you are new, this is a good place to start from.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the below document for Odoo 8.0 new API

for related fields class in new api.

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/master/reference/orm.html#fields

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Comment: I am actually asking the informations about the following :  **A common pattern in OpenERP was to do Model fields introspection using _columns property. From 8.0
_columns is deprecated by _fields that contains list of consolidated fields instantiated using old or new API.**

Comment: Chaitanya, do you have answer for this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`self._fields` it will return the fields which are available in that model to a dictionary type

`model._fields[fieldname]` will return the datatype of field as key and the field name with respective model as value

example `self._fields['price_unit']` in sale.order.line will return
 `Float: sale.order.line.price_unit`